# Syntax error in MySQL Function using Date (maybe DATEDIFF?)

Tags: mysql, sql, function, date

I have a syntax error in my MySql function but I cannot find it (it's the first time with sql so it could be a simple mistake). This is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
FUNCTION Difference(Event VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
DECLARE difference INTEGER;
SELECT DATEDIFF(e.Date, CURRENT_DATE) INTO difference
FROM Events e
WHERE e.EventName=Event;
RETURN difference;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have a table called Events with information about an event like the date. I would like to find the difference in terms of days between two events. Thank you very much and sorry for my english!

Comment: Can you show yhe error message ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION Difference(Event TEXT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE difference INT;
SELECT DATEDIFF(e.Date, CURRENT_DATE) INTO difference
FROM Events e
WHERE e.EventName=Event;
RETURN difference;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Just added CREATE,semi-colon after END, Use TEXT instead of varchar and INT instead of INTEGER.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have the same error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FUNCTION Difference(Event VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS INTEGER

Comment: Nothing :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FUNCTION Difference(Event TEXT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE difference INT;
SEL' at line 1

Comment: Add CREATE near function.....